# EF Core doesn't recognize new column name from database

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext, scaffolding, ef-core-7.0

Used scaffolding to connect to my database (mapping to a view). To the same `DbContext` I manually added two DbSets for a stored procedure.

The first stored procedure is working perfectly. In one of the stored procedures, the result set contained two equally named columns (named `text_content`). My colleague who created the stored procedure renamed one of the columns (since the equal column names got me an error). After that I still get the same error:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: text_content

It seems like the `DbContext` doesn't recognize the change made in the database. If I create a brand new project (Blazor server), scaffold again (the way I did with the other project), the error is gone.

I'm using EF Core 7.

Thank you for any help.

I tried to use migrations but it seems like only changes made in the code can be migrated to the database, and not vice versa, is that true or am I missing something here? How can I "pull the changes from the database" to my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the storedprocedure-result.cs and change the column name manually and build your project or right click your project and choose reverse engineer and click ok and build your project.

[image: ReverseEngineer]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, tried the Power Tools Reverse Engineer but it's still giving me this error (in the extensions output console):

Unable to scaffold PROCEDURE xxx as it has duplicate result column names: 'text_content'.

Answer (score 0):

Test SQL connection and check whether you included your SP in the EFcore Power tool.
[EFCoreToolImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L41To.png)